# How can I implement class that extends activity into fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

Okay, I have been breaking my head with this all day today and I would like to know if someone could help me out. I have a project where I have a simple activity that loads a json feed into a ListView and this works fine. Now, I created a new project where I have different fragments as screens. I want to place this ListView in one of the fragments but the class in the simpler project extends Activity and the fragments extends, well, Fragment. I have seen other questions answered with getActivity(), but I am not even sure how I can implement it into my own code.

This is the code for my new project's fragment:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

And this is the code for my old project:

```
package com.example.application;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Cache.Entry;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import adapter.FeedListAdapter;
import app.AppController;
import data.FeedItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://example.com/feed.json";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {
                        parseJsonFeed(response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }
    }

    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj.getString("image");
                item.setImage(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj.getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If someone can help me with this, I would be forever grateful! Thank you! Any and all help is appreciated!!

------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------

Okay, so I noticed my original question was a bit confusing. I will try to clarify here.
Project 1 has a main_activity.xml file that holds nothing but the ListView. It also has the MainActivity.java file with other helper classes but the MainActivity.java file is the main focus here. It holds the code to populate the ListView with a json file's contents. The code for that file is in the second code box above. Now, I have Project 2, this project has a main_activity.xml file that holds a linear layout that is populated with one of five different fragments when I click on a button. Now, there's a home_fragment.xml file that a HomeFragment.java file for this fragment. I want the home_fragment.xml file to hold the ListView and I want to add the code in the second code box into this file, but the contents of the HomeFragment.java file is the first code box. I know I cannot extend Fragment and Activity so how can I add the code in code box 2, to my HomeFragment.java file.

Comment: So you want your listview in the fragment and your activity must host this fragment. If this is what you want?

Comment: Same question with Fabin. Please make your requirement more clearly. I tried to read all but don't understand what do you want.

Comment: Yeah. You see, in the original project, I have a layout file that holds the listview and then the main activity, which is the one that you see on my original question. My new project has the main layout file that holds five fragments that are toggled through with buttons. I want one of the fragments to hold that same list view and have that fragments class to hold the code but the fragment's class already extends fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what i understood, your home_fragment.xml should be like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and your main HomeFragment should be like this

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private ListView listView;
private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private String URL_FEED = "http://example.com/feed.json";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    feedItems = new ArrayList<>();

    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity(), feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
    if (entry != null) {
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, URL_FEED, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                if (response != null) {
                    parseJsonFeed(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }
    return view;
}

private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

            String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj.getString("image");
            item.setImage(image);
            item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
            item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
            item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

            String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj.getString("url");
            item.setUrl(feedUrl);

            feedItems.add(item);
        }

        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I hope it helps you...

Comment: It looks like it wants to work but I am running into one issue. When I am trying to declare TAG as such:
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

All of the lines that hold JsonObjectRequest jsonReq, turn red and I get the following error:

Cannot resolve constructor 'JsonObjectRequest(int, java.lang.String, null, anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener<org.json.JSONObject>, anonymous com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener)'

Comment: Glad I could help...:)